# How do I render an `HTMLCanvasElement` in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a utility which produces a thumbnail for a video and returns it as an `HTMLCanvasElement`. I'd like to render that element in React, like so:

```
render () {
   return (
      <div className='video-thumbnail'>
         {this.props.videoThumbnailCanvas}
      </div>
   );
}
```

But when I try that, I get an error that:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLCanvasElement]).

What's a good way to do this? One idea is to do direct DOM manipulation from `componentDidMount` (e.g. `React.getDOMNode(this).appendChild(this.props.videoThumbnailCanvas)`), but that seems rather hack-like.

Comment: Do you control the utility function? Can you have it return a `<canvas></canvas>` JSX element instead?

Comment: @DannyDelott -- I do control it. It currently looks something like this:

'
function getThumb() {
    let canvas:HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (context) {
        context.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, w, h);
    }
    return canvas;
}
'

I am not sure how I would draw to the `context` with a JSX element.

Comment: I believe you cannot use `document.creteElement` in your `getThumb()`

Comment: @Muhaimin: why not? It does work.

Comment: it's wrong practise

Comment: found an excellent article doing the same; https://blog.cloudboost.io/using-html5-canvas-with-react-ff7d93f5dc76

Answer (score 9):

I got the same problem and you can solve in 2 ways:

the easy way:

```
render () {
   const src = this.props.videoThumbnailCanvas.toDataURL();
   return (
      <div className='video-thumbnail'>
         <img src={src} />
      </div>
   );
}
```

the other way i like more (but is personal):

```
onComponentDidMount() {
  const element = document.getElementById('uniquePlaceHolderKey');
  element.parentNode.replaceChild(this.props.videoThumbnailCanvas, element);
}

render () {
   return (
      <div className='video-thumbnail'>
         <div id="uniquePlaceHolderKey" ></div>
      </div>
   );
}
```

This second solution lets you load a temp element that you will swap with your own painted canvas instance. I did not found a proper react solution to force the appending of a pre rendered canvas element.
There are proper react methods to get an element of a component ( like `this.findDomNode()` ) that are preferable to getElementById since work on the component instance.

Comment: so I thought about using toDataURL, but unfortunately that only works if the video from which the canvas was captured is sourced from same-domain or cross-domain that allows access. This is not guaranteed in my case. When that's not the case, toDataURL() fails with an error that "tainted" (written with data from another domain) canvas cannot be exported.

Your second suggestion does entail doing a direct DOM insertion, which I can also do with the actual canvas (without toDataURL()). This currently stands as the most reasonable way, but it seems very anti-pattern for React.

Comment: it is an anti pattern. you are inserting thing react does not know about. is also true react does not give you an alternative. Is more performant of dataurl and you can keep it alive using the react component lifecycle

Comment: oh yes the dataurl in  second example is a copy paste error